# how to know the region location of my firebase storage?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

for my firestore database, I can clearly see the location of my database, like in this image

[image]

but I can't find out the default location of my firebase storage to store my images. I only find the bucket name

[image]

how to find the default region location of my firebase storage ? I need to ensure the location is the nearest from my user

is it always be the same as Default GCP resource location  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The region of a project's default storage bucket is the same as Firestore.  You actually agreed to set it that way in a dialog at some point during project setup.  Please read the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/locations):

> Cloud Firestore and Cloud Storage — If you start using either of these products, you're prompted to select your project's default Google Cloud Platform (GCP) resource location (if it wasn't already selected when setting up another service).

Answer (score 1):

Just came across this because I needed the same. The accepted answer does not tell you how to find it, if you don't know what was selected previously. And if the project in question already has a Storage configured, but not Firestore.

It turns out that you only need to open the project settings in the Firebase console (accessible from the little cog on the top), and there it will tell you the Default GCP resource location (third item from the top). It is not set for projects where this has not yet been selected, but it is fixed for projects where you already selected it either when first setting up Storage or Firestore.